# Could ballistic electron transport be used for transmission lines and undersea cables?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, semiconductor-physics, electronics

Ballistic conduction, from what I know, resembles superconductivity sans the Meissner effect. But unlike superconductivity it can occur at room temperature.Has there been any R&D in the use of ballistic conduction for transmission lines and undersea cables? I've heard about attempts to develop superconducting power lines but never any usage of ballistic conduction in this area. Ditto for submarine cables.

Comment: IIRC, ballistic transport has only been observed in nanostructures.

Comment: Normal ballistic transport only happens over very short length scales -- maybe microns at cryogenic temperatures. Over longer length scales, the elections scatter, and the transport is no longer ballistic; it's diffusive. Or to oversimplify it: if you make a wire short enough, its resistance goes away (ballistic transport). If you make the wire longer, the resistance comes back (diffusive transport). It should be clear why ballistic transport won't help for long cables.